# Where is my base station? Airport utility app question

Tags: airport

My airport utility app does not show a base station but allows me to restart it. How do I find the remote base station? I never purchased one.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot so we can see what you see?

Comment: The 'Restart…' menu item normally only un-greys once you select an actual base station. If you don't own one & the app doesn't list one, it's far more likely to be a bug/glitch in the app than a magic invisible base station you are certain you don't own.